# How to retrieve User Token with server side app integration

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

The objective is extremely simple, yet there are no examples on how to retrieve the user token associated to the currently running app.

My objective is to just pull my public facebook page (business page with complete open access) with the app I have created in facebook that I mere created just to get an app id and secret so I can have PHP perform the request for the data and then iterate it on my homepage. Very simple, yet the documentation on the site mainly deals with facebook logins which I have no intention of doing. I just want my feeds from the public business page on the site.

This is where I think Facebook goes horribly wrong. Here is my code so far that queries properly but generates an empty data set:

```
$app_id = "APP_ID";
$app_secret = "APP_SECRET";
$app_token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
    . "client_id=" . $app_id
    . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret
    . "&grant_type=client_credentials";

    $response = file_get_contents($app_token_url);
    $params = null;
parse_str($response, $params);

$graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/202978003068170/feed?access_token=".$params['access_token'];

$app_details = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url), true);


    echo '<pre>';
            var_dump($app_details);
    echo '<pre>';
```

Now let my clarify what the actual `access_token` value is because Facebook is vague ambiguous about this. There are actually two types of access tokens and the app I have created has *both* types which if you are logged in and working on your app you can see here:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/

The major problem is the `access_token` value that oauth returns from the code above is the "App Token" which has no problem querying for User Profile data (which is kinda scary) but returns blank data when I try to query my Public business page `{"data":[]}` that I have enabled all the permissions for. After a week of trying out different methods and slamming my head on the desk and only finding partial salvation through third party sources of information did I figure out the difference between these two.

I have ran across a post on here that said I have to do a 2nd OAUTH query to pull the App's "user token" (which I have tested the user token associated to the app token from the token debugger in fbook and it works) to Facebook but what does that query consist.

Please someone help. This should not be this difficult, I am not wanting users to login to my site with fbook. I just want to display by business events, feeds and pictures on my business website.

Thank you